# Setup application while installation on android

Tags: android, installation

Is it possible to setup (unzip some archives) while (or right after) installation the app on a Android device? I mean I need to execute some code (on java or ndk).

Comment: no, you can't execute any code while/after your app is installed. only during first launch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. it is not possible.

the application VM is only instantiated after the user have opened it at least once.

That's by design part of the security model of the Android framework, if the user decides that an application is suspicious and he would not want to have it, the application still cannot run any code.